# printing array not working

Tags: php

hello everyone i am printing array from the database in the following format

```
Array ( [0] => 14
        [task_id] => 14
        [1] => 123
        [user_id] => 123
        [2] => 456
        [employee_id] => 456
        [3] => 2
        [service_id] => 2
        [4] => 2:00 AM
        [starttime] => 2:00 AM
        [5] => 4:00 AM
        [endtime] => 4:00 AM
        [6] => se a
        [servicename] => se a
        [7] => ddsdsd
        [servicedescription] => ddsdsd
        [8] => dsd
        [employeename] => dsd
        [9] => pictures/noimage.gif
        [employeepicture] => pictures/noimage.gif
        [10] => pictures/noimage.gif
        [pic_path] => pictures/noimage.gif )
```

It is the result of

```
$rd = $this->executeQuery();
$recordsArray = array(); 
while (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rd)) ){
$recordsArray[] = $row;
```

problem is how can i pick the single record from it like this

```
echo $row[$task_id]; // not working
```

Thanks

Comment: I suggest to read the array documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need quotes around the key for this to work:

```
 echo $row['task_id'];
```

Good-luck!

Comment: i am able to fetch by echo $row[1]; not by the name instead of putting ''

Comment: @user: Did you also remove the `$`? Do you have it exactly like the code posted in the answer? It will work, definitely.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo $row['task_id'];
```

maybe it's a syntax error?

Comment: i am able to fetch by echo $row[1]; not by the name instead of putting ''

Comment: since there is an index [1] it will return that value, your task id matched index [0].... I'm not sure what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

It's won't work, because you need to iterate the whole $recordsArray to the the right $row.

You can solve this by saving a row as an hash in the $recordsArray instead of an enumurated array like this:

```
$recordsArray[$row['task_id']] = $row;
```

Now you can fetch the row from the records array like this:

```
$recordsArray[$task_id];
```

(provided that $task_id exists).

Answer (score 0):

You would do that by limiting your SQL query using a where clause to get the correct record.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this
 echo $row['task_id'];
it will work....

Answer (score 0):

You make a mistake in Syntax
you can try this:

```
echo $row['task_id'];
```